# (?=regex) VS (?:regex)

Tags: javascript, regex

What is difference between `(?=regex)` and `(?:regex)` in JavaScript?

Explain it with an example,Please.

Comment: An explanation and example are provided for each by MDN under "[Special characters meaning in regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions)."

Comment: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds

Comment: You might also try Stack Overflow's Documentation on Regex – [Capture Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/660/capture-groups), [Lookahead and Lookbehind](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/639/lookahead-and-lookbehind)

Comment: This is the first result in Google, so it probably meets the users questionning

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`(?=regex)` is a positive lookahead, it matches a group after the main expression without including it in the result.
Example:

```
\d(?=px)
1pt 2px 3em 4px
```

This will only match the `2` and the `4`, not the entire `2px` and `4px`.

`(?:regex)` is a non-capturing group, it groups multiple tokens together without creating a capture group.
Example:

```
(?:ha)+
hahaha haa hah!
```

This will match each `ha`, but not create a group for it.